# manipulating excel spreadsheets with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, excel-2010, string-search

I am new to Python especially when it comes to using it with Excel. I need to write code to search for the string “Mac”, “Asus”, “AlienWare”, “Sony”, or “Gigabit” within a longer string for each cell in column A. Depending on which of these strings it finds within the entire entry in column A’s cell, it should write one of these 5 strings to the corresponding row in column C’s cell. Else if it doesn’t find any of the five, it would write “Other” to the corresponding row in column C. For example, if Column A2’s cell contained the string “ProLiant Asus DL980 G7, the correct code would write “Asus” to column C2’s cell. It should do this for every single cell in column A, writing the appropriate string to the corresponding cell in column C. Every cell in column A will have one of the five strings Mac, Asus, AlienWare, Sony, or Gigabit within it. If it doesn’t contain one of those strings, I want the corresponding cell in column 3 to have the string “Other” written to it. So far, this is the code that I have (not much at all):

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.active
    for i in range (sheet.max_row):
    cell1 = sheet.cell (row = i, column = 1)
    cell2 = sheet.cell (row = I, column = 3)

# missing code here

wb.save(path)
```

Comment: Are you just asking for the code to achieve this?  Or did you have a specific question?

Comment: I have figured out a different way to do this without using the helpful ideas below (to fit my specific need), but am having one specific issue. I can get my code to write to the excel spreadsheet but only if I designate a specific row (thus just filling in one cell). If I use row = i (trying to iterate through all the rows), I get an error saying "ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1" but obviously I'm trying to fill in the entire third column and leave the code open to adjustments in the number of rows. I am probably making a simple but ignorant mistake.

Comment: ok i figured it out guys. thanks for your help. I simply needed to change "i" to "i+1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't tried writing any code to solve the problem. You might want to first get openpyxl to write to the excel workbook and verify that is working - even if it's dummy data. This page looks helpful - [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

Once that is working all you'd need is a simple function that takes in a string as an argument.

```
def get_column_c_value(string_from_column_a):
     if "Lenovo" in string_from_column_a:
          return "Lenovo"
     else if "HP" in string_from_column_a:
          return "HP"
     # strings you need to check for here in the same format as above
     else return "other"
```

Try out those and if you have any issues let me know where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Of course! I'm happy to help if you run into issues just comment here!

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked much with openpyxl, but it sounds like you are trying to do a simple string search.

You can access individual cells by using

```
cell1.internal_value
```

Then, your if/else statement would look something like

```
if "HP" in str(cell1.internal_value):
```

Data can be assigned directly to a cell so you could have

```
ws['C' + str(i)] = "HP"
```

You could do this for all of the data in your cells

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try!